# Can I bypass try_files based on a condition (HTTP method) in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have nginx proxying to php-fpm with the following config:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /vol/app/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Everything is working great until a DELETE request comes in like:

`DELETE /?file&path=foo`

When this happens nginx returns a 405 (method not allowed) and doesn't appear to proxy the request to php-fpm.

Is there a way to bypass the `try_files`directive when it's a `DELETE` request and just proxy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912270/how-do-i-allow-a-put-file-request-on-nginx-server maybe?